# How to change drawable color of a view in linear layout programmatically?

Tags: android

I have a linear layout with three views in it. I want to change the drawable color of star_one view programmatically, How can I do that?

I have tried these three line of code one by one, but none worked.

```
linearLayout.getChildAt(0).getRootView().getBackground().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

linearLayout.getChildAt(0).getBackground().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

linearLayout.getChildAt(0).getBackground().setColorFilter( getResources().getColor(R.color.red), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY );
```

Here is my XML code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/power_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/star_power_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/star_power_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/star_power_left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
linearLayout.getChildAt(0).setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for my late reply. Btw that didn't worked either but instead I tried to findViewById in linear layout.